# Shortcut to send telnet session to background conflicts with Cisco terminal shortcut: Ctrl+Z.How do I change that?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

My Linux machine has no GUI. I use it as a jump box from where I telnet/ssh on my routers to configure

The shortcut to send a process to background in Unix is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
On the same time the shortcut to exit the config mode for a Cisco router is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

So if you are configuring a Cisco router from the command prompt in Linux there is no way (or at least I don't know one) to send the telnet/ssh session to background so you can open a new one.

How do I fix that?

I am thinking of either changing the shortcuts or using a telnet/ssh manager that would work in text mode. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the suspend char using [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html). In your case, for example, you can disable the "suspend" ability with

```
stty susp undef
```

or change it to for example `ctrl`-`E` with

```
stty susp '^E'
```

and you can check it:

```
[romano:~/Downloads/mps] % sleep 1000 
^E
[1]  + 2681 suspended  sleep 1000
1z [romano:~/Downloads/mps] 20 % fg
[1]  + 2681 continued  sleep 1000
^Z
```

`stty -a` gives you all the special chars:

```
[romano:~/Downloads/mps] % stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 114; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q;
stop = ^S; susp = ^E; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

... although after re-reading the question you will probably greatly benefit from a terminal multiplexer, as [@Shaun suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/600280/16395).  My personal favorite is the good old `screen`, which [has a lot of tutorial around](http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/), even in the written form which I prefer to videos...

Comment: I decided to reward/accept this answer as it addresses the question directly. the other answer is also good and actually that is what I needed but I poorly formulated my question. In other words, this is the solution to my question but I will use one of the utils mentioned by shaun. I would love to be able to reward both answers

Comment: the funny thing is that screen has Ctrl+Z as Suspend which again conflicts with the Cisco shortcut

Comment: and there is another thing that conflicts with the Cisco shortcuts: Ctrl+a which I use to get at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 3):

I think for your case, I'd investigate byobu/screen/tmux (I believe byobu is the go-to on ubuntu, screen is more prevalent on other linuxes, and tmux on BSDs).

A picture is worth a thousand words here, so sticking 'byobu' into youtube will explain the concept much quicker than I can in words.  But they're terminal multiplexers, which allow you to start concurrent shells from within byobu, and allow you to 'tab' between them.  This alone would solve your issue, but digging a little deeper into their other features may also benefit your workflow - eg, split-panes allowing you to, for example, examine running-config on two routers side-by-side, rather than flicking between them.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I think I will try one of the above mentioned utils.